# Internet Explorer/jQuery focus problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

If you open the following [url](http://jackson.elevationimaging.com/cgi-bin/category.cgi?category=staging) in Internet Explorer (IE6/7/8) and hover over the "Find Portrait" link a popup shows up. When you try to select a value from the month or year dropdown, Internet Explorer loses focus and the popup closes. It shouldn't close. This happens only in Internet Explorer. jQuery v.1.3.2 is used for the events handling. Any suggestions about this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Trying to access your page... I guess everybody's doing the same, coz it's so damn slow! :P

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using mouseover and mouseout functions. Try using [hover()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) instead, that should consider nested elements for you.

The problem is that when you hover the `SELECT` element, actually your "leaving" your bubble, and it's closed.

As I said, use [hover()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) instead.

Comment: Could you please post your new code? You should use hover() with both the bubble and the links. Also, consider using a flag as mkoryak said: whenever you enter the nav and bubble, set a common variable to TRUE; when out, set it to FALSE. So, whenever you want to hide the bubble, check if that flag is set to TRUE or not; that'll tell you if the user's over one of the two things.

Comment: @Sed, I tried it with a flag - worked fine. The problem actually comes from the event bubbling. When you "leave" the <select> element this triggers an event that "bubbles" through the parent elements. So simply adding stopPropagation() to the 'mouseout' function for the <select> element fixes the problem. Apparently, there are some other issues like the fact that this doesn't quote work all the time, but I will spend more time on it tomorrow. 'setTimeout' will probably be the key when fighting around with IE. Thank you Seb for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

on the mouseout handler, do not hide the box before checking a flag. set the flag when you mouse over the date picker, and unset it when you mouseout.